# How to get child of div in cheerio

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cheerio

I am working with cheerio and I am stuck at a point where I want to get the href value of children div of `<div class="card">`.

```
<div class="Card">  
   <div class="title">
    <a target="_blank" href="test">
        Php </a>
    </div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
 </div>
```

I got first childern correctly but i want to get `div class=title` childern `a`  href value. I am new to node and i already search for that but i didn't get an appropriate answer.

var jobs = $("div.jobsearch-SerpJobCard",html);

here is my script

```
 const rp = require('request-promise');
 const $  = require('cheerio');
 const potusParse = require('./potusParser');
 const url = "";

 rp(url)
   .then((html)=>{
     const Urls = [];
      var jobs = $("div.Card",html);


      for (let i = 2; i < jobs.length; i++) {
         Urls.push(
                $("div.Card  > div[class='title'] >a", html)[i].attribs.href
     );
   }
  console.log(Urls);


   })

     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: The HTML you posted is incorrect `class="Card` misses the closing quote, but probably that's a copy-paste thing

Comment: yes that is just copy pasting

Comment: `var hrefs = []; $('div.Card .title a').each(function(index, element) { hrefs.push(element.href); });` - this should do what you need

Comment: no it is not working returning nll array []

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve, please update the HTML to match the task you are trying to do.

Comment: i scrap data from a web which return me `HTML`  from which i select `Card`  div which contain `div having class title` and i want to get `anchor ` tag from that div child

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks something like this:

```
$('.Card').map((i, card) => {
  return {
    link: $(card).find('a').text(),
    href: $(card).find('a').attr('href'),
  }
}).get()
```

Edit: the nlp library is [chrono-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrono-node) and I also recommend [timeago.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeago.js/v/4.0.0-beta.3) to go the opposite way

Comment: Yes, it is the right thing I was looking for and thanks for your response. I just want to ask a question can I generate date from the string like `2 days` or `5 days` in node? like I got detail about that is posted `2 days ago`, and i can create date from that string?

Comment: Yes you are looking for a natural language date parser, I'm sure there is a good js library for that.